# Camel Bindy return 0 instead of null (empty)

Tags: apache-camel, export-to-csv, bindy

If the input data is null, when marshaling using my Bindy model (elToCSV) :

```
@DataField(pos = 7)  int nbRoom;
```

and route as follow:

```
from("direct:start").bean(ELProcessor.class,"myMethod").marshal(elToCSV).to("file:" + outFolder + "?fileName=test.csv");
```

it sets automatically a 0 and not an empty field into my output.

is there any parameters to define that i've missed ?

thanks

Comment: Use `Integer` instead of `int`?

Comment: Perhaps you may accept my answer below so that it is visible for everybody that the problem is solved...?

Comment: Yes of course sorry first time in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field with the type `int` can not be set to `null`. This is just not possible in Java. Use `Integer` instead for `nbRoom`.